# Partial sum when using roll_sum

Tags: r, partial, rolling-computation, rolling-sum

I use `rolling_sum` to create a 3-month rolling sum for one column. However, it creates `NA` for rows with `now() <3` while I'd like to see partial sum there. There is a `Partial` argument in the documentation, but says it is not currently implemented!

Here is my data and what I'd like to see:

```
df =
id   date   variable   3_month_sum_current   3-month_sum_needed
1    1      1          NA                    1
1    2      0          NA                    1
1    3      2          3                     3
1    4      4          6                     6
```

my code:

```
library(RcppRoll)
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%group_by(id) %>% arrange(date) %>%
      mutate(3_month_sum_current = 
             roll_sum(variable, 3, fill=NA, align= 'right', partial = TRUE)
```

Comment: `rollapplyr` in the zoo package has a partial= argument.

Answer (score 3):

*rollapplyr* in the *zoo* package has a `partial=` argument.